# Cannot create LinkedIn Controller bean with Spring Social

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

I have built a simple application to connect my app with linkedIn. I have modeled it after the Spring Social Example app for Facebook: 
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/

In that tutorial, one can just add the appId and appSecret in the application.properties file in the classpath to connect to Facebook. According to Spring,

"The presence of these properties and Spring Social Twitter in the classpath will trigger automatic configuration of Spring Social’s ConnectController, TwitterConnectionFactory, and other components of Spring Social’s connection framework."

As a result, I assumed that doing the same thing for LinkedIn would wire-up the same connection framework. I have made an **application.yml** file that contains the following properties:

```
spring:
  social:
    linkedin:
      consumerKey: {{someKey}}
      consumerSecret:{{someSecret}}
```

Then I made a LinkedInController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LinkedInController {

    private LinkedIn linkedIn;

    private ConnectionRepository userConnectionRepository;

    @Inject
    public LinkedInController(LinkedIn linkedIn, ConnectionRepository userConnectionRepository) {
        this.linkedIn = linkedIn;
        this.userConnectionRepository = userConnectionRepository;
        }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model) {

    if (userConnectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class) == null) {
        return "redirect:/auth/linkedin";
    }

    LinkedInProfile profile = linkedIn.profileOperations().getUserProfile();
    System.out.println(profile.getFirstName());
    return "hello";
    }

}
```

However, this doesn't create the LinkedInController bean:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'linkedInController' defined in file [/Users/hankekimm/Documents/safx/target/classes/com/safx/web/api/LinkedInController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I am not sure what is the issue here. Is there a problem with my properties file? Or is it something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old post. But hope it could help to someone else. I had a similar problem and **problem was in the property file**.

Correct format is:

```
spring:
  social:
    linkedin:
      appId: {{someKey}}
      appSecret:{{someSecret}}
```